# How to add a new column to sqlite with java

Tags: java, sqlite

How can I add a new column to a Sqlite table in Java and keep the data. I have seen and used the onUpgrade method in Android, but I have not found anything similar in "native java"

My database is a file previously loaded with the entire table structure and in this way I make the connection to it:

```
public static Connection sqliteInit() {
    
    
    Connection cnx = null;
    String bd= System.getProperty("user.home")+File.separator +".local"+File.separator+"assets"+File.separator+"app_database.db";
    String url = "jdbc:sqlite:"+bd;
    try {Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    cnx = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        
    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return cnx;
}
```

Comment: Read this: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Statement stmt = cnx.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate("alter table ...");
```